# Cron задача. Проблема с запуском скрипта

Tags: php, cron, скрипт, phpquery

Pre Scriptum. На пхп я не кодил от слова совсем.

Написал небольшой скрипт на php для парсинга отзывов с сайта яндекса. Скрипт подключает библиотеку `phpQuery`, отправляет запрос, дальше foreach - ом пробегаюсь по массиву из dom и создаю json файл.
В случае если появились новые отзывы, то скрипт сравнивает их с записанными отзывами и если их нет, то дописывает в конец файла.

Инклуд билиотеки: `include './phpQuery-onefile.php';`

Запрос к яндексу: `$html = file_get_contents($url);`

Чтение существующего файла: `$output_file = file_get_contents($out_path);`

И запись: `file_put_contents($out_path, json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));`

Out_Path: `$out_path = './public_html/reviews.json';`

Разрабатывал на open_server, но также проверил скрипт на xampp. На локалке все отлично работает, файл дописывается.

Далее перенес скрипт на хостинг создал cron задачу. Файл скрипта и библиотеки закинул в корневую папку, а файл reviews.json закинул в public_html. (т.к. к json буду обращаться из сайта)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске скрипта он падает с ошибкой exit 255. Обратился в службе поддержки, но там ничем не смогли помочь. Хостинг - beget. Аналогично закинул, кхм..., на timeweb - там вообще не пишутся ошибки ну и файл не обновляется.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и где косяк?

UPD. Beget сказали, что проблем с запросами на сторонние ресурсы нет, а в логах появляется ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpQuery' not found in...
```

в этой строке: `$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($html);`

Что с ней не так - надо по-другому использовать пространство имен ? или в cron нет возможности заинклудить библиотеку?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда используйте абсолютные пути для include/require:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/phpQuery-onefile.php';
```

При запуске из CRON(и не только), текущая директория(`./`) не та, какую вы ожидаете.

Comment: Дополните ответ, будет хорошо если напишите какая домашняя директория будет у крона и почему.

Comment: Хм, так я не курсе, какая будет текущая. Мне это ни к чему. Это может быть $HOME пользователя от которого установлена crontab, а может быть что-то другое в каком-нибудь другом дистре.

Comment: Да, это помогло спасибо. Только абсолютные пути нужно было прописать не только в include/require, но и к файлу который читается / в который записываются данные

Comment: При большой легаси кодовой базе может иметь смысл вызов `chdir(__DIR__);` =)